# Has anyone encountered "Labio de niña" within Spanish literature or perhaps the plant world?

Tags: traducción, plantas

Rubén Darío, in a poem written around 1890 (*"Reencarnaciones"*) speaks of "labio de niña" which I have interpreted as a type of flower which appears very much like human lips (called "Hooker's Lips" in places, scientific name *psychotria elata*). I cannot confirm this. But it seems a better translation than one I see often ("a young girl's lips that yields") since a splicing of a girl's lips between vegetal matter and a lark in this way seems jarring.

> Yo fui coral primero,
>   después hermosa piedra,
>   después fui de los bosques verde y colgante hiedra;
>   después yo fui manzana,
>   lirio de la campiña,
>   labio de niña,
>   una alondra cantando en la mañana;
>   y ahora soy un alma
>   que canta como canta una palma
>   de luz de Dios al viento.

Comment: The answer written by @ukemi has convinced me that the poet was talking about a flower/plant, as you suspected.  But it also appears it's not the flamboyant plant you were suspecting.  That fits in better, I think, with the historical period in which the poem was written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Plants

While there do exist [similar](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25802/what-is-a-palma-de-luz?#comment42350_25802) common names for [*Psychotria poeppigiana*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychotria_poeppigiana#Nombres_comunes)<sup>1</sup>, *"labio de niña"* appears to be a common name for a couple of different species of plant:

### Locustberries / Serrettes (*Byrsonima*)

[image: https://www.flickr.com/photos/minassaomuitas/15870505969]

> Otras especies reportadas son el chuguacá hojiancho (Hyeronima macrocarpa), hojarasco (Talauma caricifragans), cerezo (Callophyllum sp.), chuguacá hojipequeño (Hyeronima colombiana), **labio de niña (Byrsonima sp.)**, cereza (Ruagea glabra), Granizo (Posoqueria latifolia), ...

- [*Plan de manejo ambiental de la Cuchilla de Peñas Blancas y del Subia,* Departamento de Cundinamarca](http://sie.car.gov.co/bitstream/handle/20.500.11786/33814/29622.pdf)

### Otoba (*O. parvifolia*)

[image: http://arbolesdeucayali.blogspot.co.uk/2017/03/otoba-parvifolia-markgr-ah-gentry.html]

> Cerca al río Siare y caño las Viejitas se encuentran las especies: Peralejo (pera arborea), Ajicito (Humiria sp), Arrayán (Myrcia sp), Gallino (pentagonia); papelillo (simaruoba amara), **labio de niña (dialyanthera parvifolia)**; cabo de hacha (Aspidosperma oblongum); Chaparro montañero (Hieronyma laxiflota) y caraño (Dacryopes sp).

- [*Plan de Desarrollo "La Fuerza del Pueblo 2016-2019"*, Mapiripán Meta](https://ceo.uniandes.edu.co/images/Documentos/Plan_de_Desarrollo-_Mapirip%C3%A1n.pdf)

### Quaruba (*Vochysia ferruginea Mart.*)

[image: http://ctfs.si.edu/webatlas/findinfo.php?specid=8799&leng=english]

> **SOROGA DORMILÓN**
> **Nombre científico:** Vochysia ferruginea Mart.
> **Familia:** Vochysiaceae
> **Nombres comunes:** Gomo, Goma, Almidón, Bizcochito, Corocito, Cacho de venado, Cajú, Kamusanakee, Kuana, **Labio de niña**, Peerai-Kai, Suruma, Tidutí, Tumuko **(Col.)**; Laguno, Chimbulla (Ecu.); Quillosisa, Shambo caspi (Perú); Saladillo (Ven.); Cedro rana, Pau de vinho, Pau de vinho preto, Vinheiro do matto, Guaricica (Bras.); Prefontaine bois (Guy.); Kwari, MotiKwarie, Wane.

- [*Propiedades, Usos y Nominación de Especies Vegetales de la Amazonía Colombiana.*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=Gr5fAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=labio) - p.[117](https://www.scribd.com/document/244512973/MARCO-TEORICO-docx)

> [image]
>
> [image]

- [Xycol: Fiche: *Vochysia ferruginea* Mart., 1826](http://www.xycol.net/index.php?categorie=200&op=fiche&liste_resultat_active=6&appellation_nsr=Vochysia+ferruginea+Mart.%2C+1826)

---

[image]

- https://www.cornare.gov.co/boletin_oficial/2011/Septiembre/9502.pdf

---

## Literature

Literarily the phrase only seems to make another appearance as a translation of the (literal) French *"lèvre enfantine"* in Arthur Rimbaud's (1854-1891) poem [*La maline* (*La tunata*)](https://poemasenfrances.blogspot.co.uk/2004/09/arthur-rimbaud-la-maline.html):

And as *labio**s*** *de niña* (again, literally) in Darío's own *"Mi tía Rosa"* (1923):

> Y en tanto que escuchaba vuestros reproches, bajo la tempestad de vuestro regaño, miraba flamear como un estandarte real la más opulenta y perfumada de las cabelleras rubias; y pensaba en la roja corola de los dos más lindos **labios de niña**; tras cuyo cerco de raso estaba la miel ultraterrestre de la más dulce fruta; y oía la voz amorosa que primeramente me despertara a la pasión de las pasiones; y bajo mis dedos nerviosos y avaros todo el tesoro columbino, y el del oro y el del marfil y el del rubí ¡el ala del cisne, la onda, la lira! No; no era yo, pues, el culpable; no fuí más que un nuevo instrumento de la infinita orquesta; y por furioso, por loco, por sonoro que fuese, no haría más que el mínimo gorrión de los árboles, o del más pequeño pez de las aguas.

- [Rubén Darío, *Cuentos*](http://sajurin.enriquebolanos.org/vega/docs/LL_RubenDarioCuentosJoseEmilioBalladares.pdf) - Rojo, Relatos sombríos (p.141)

---

**Notes:**

1. > <sup>Es conocida localmente como **labios ardientes, labios de la novia**,<sup>3</sup>​ **flor de labios, beso de negra** y sombrerito del diablo.<sup>2</sup>​</sup>